# JQuery Ajax UrlAction Changes the Pages URL MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, post

I am using .Net Core MVC to build my application. Here I have to refresh the chart by selected criteria. So, when I select the criteria and post the action, the action works but It doesn't refresh my Chart. In addition, when I check from the Developer Tools -> Network I see the following error.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: The view 'UpdateChart' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Home/UpdateChart.cshtml /Views/Shared/UpdateChart.cshtml
```

Here is my script

```
function GetData() {
var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
       var data = table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '@Url.Action("UpdateChart","Home")', //"/Home/UpdateChart",
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           data: data,
           dataType: "html",
           success: function (result) {
               myFunction();
               console.log(result);
           }
       });
   }

window.onload = function myFunction() {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
   zoomEnabled: true,
   title: {
       text: '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartText)'//"My Text"
   },
   axisX: {
       title: "chart updates every 2 secs",
       crosshair: {
           enabled: true,
           snapToDataPoint: true
       }
   },
   axisY: {
       crosshair: {
           enabled: true,
           snapToDataPoint: true,
           valueFormatString: "#,##0"
       }
   },
   toolTip: {
       shared: true
   },
   legend: {
       dockInsidePlotArea: true,
       verticalAlign: "top",
       horizontalAlign: "right"
   },
   data: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.AllData)
});

       chart.render();

   }
```

Here is my View

```
<div class="collapse show" id="collapseCardExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
                    <form id="formId" role="form">
                        <label></label>
                        <select class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.CustomerDevices"></select>
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="90%" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Select All</th>
                                    @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                                    {
                                        <th> @col.Caption</th>
                                    }
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="chkBox" value="@row.ItemArray[0]"></td>
                                        @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                                        {
                                            <td>
                                                @cell.ToString()
                                            </td>
                                        }
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <button type="button" id="getDataBtn" class="btn btn-success" onclick="GetData();">Update Chart</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateChart()
        {
            ChartRepository repository = new ChartRepository();

            string deviceSerialNo = HttpContext.Session.GetString("currentSerialNumber") != null ? HttpContext.Session.GetString("currentSerialNumber").ToString() : "1606008363";
            string selectedDataTypes = HttpContext.Request.Form["chkBox"].ToString();

            string query = repository.PrepSelectQuery(selectedDataTypes, deviceSerialNo, "2021-03-05 10:44:55.544398", "2021-03-11 12:44:55.544398");

            GeneralObjects.ServiceResponse response = repository.GetChartData(query);

            if (response.Return_Code != 0)
                return (ActionResult)Error();

            //string dataName = repository.GetDataTypeName(Convert.ToInt32(arr[i]));
            ViewBag.AllData = response.This_Object;
            return View();
        }
```

Debugger comes to `UpdateChart()` function but doesn't refresh the chart.

Thanks in advance for your suggesstions.

Comment: the error is very clear, you don't have any `UpdateChart.cshtml` located in these places: `/Views/Home/UpdateChart.cshtml`, `/Views/Shared/UpdateChart.cshtml`. This `return View()` will implicitly invoke the view named `UpdateChart` (same as the action name).

Comment: Where is the view file located in the folder structure?  As @KingKing stated, it may be missing the file in the right folder.

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to do is refresh the page by the Action ```UpdateChart``` Controller ```Home``` . So In this case shouldn't I return the ```View()``` ?

Comment: If you use ajax to post method, it will not refresh the whole page, I suggest you could try to use some js function like location function to redirect or refresh the page after successfully execute the post method.